# Case When bringing back two lines rather than one

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2016

Hi all I have some code I'm working on, and what I need to do I'm sure is relatively easy, however I'm struggling on a Case statement

What I need to do;
Bring back the data set to make into a table within SSRS, split by Year, then Usage Month, then by Billing Tier

Issue;
Billing Tiers are 0,1,4,5
0 is historic data and I need to show this as 1, then add 0 and original tier 1 together

What I've done so far;

```
DECLARE @UsageMonth DATE = '20170401'
DECLARE @YEAR INT = '2017'
DECLARE @BillingTier2 INT = 1;

SELECT  YEAR(UsageMonth) AS [Year],
        UsageMonth,
        --Billingtier,
        CASE WHEN billingtier = 0 THEN 1 ELSE billingtier END AS BillingTier2,
        SuppliesBilled = COUNT(DISTINCT c.CoreMPAN),
        CreditKwH = SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsCredit = 1 THEN c.ConsumptionUnits ELSE 0 END),
        DebitKwH = SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsCredit = 0 THEN c.ConsumptionUnits ELSE 0 END),
        TotalKwh = SUM(c.ConsumptionUnits),
        CreditAmount = SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsCredit = 1 THEN c.ConsumptionAmount ELSE 0 END),
        DebitAmount = SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsCredit = 0 THEN c.ConsumptionAmount ELSE 0 END),
        TotalAmount= SUM(c.ConsumptionAmount),
        UnitRate = SUM(c.ConsumptionAmount) / NULLIF(SUM(c.ConsumptionUnits), 0),
        StandingCharge = SUM(c.StandingChargeAmount),
        CCL = SUM(c.CCLAmount)

FROM    dbo.table1 c
WHERE YEAR(UsageMonth) = @YEAR
AND UsageMonth = @UsageMonth
GROUP BY YEAR(UsageMonth), UsageMonth, Billingtier, CASE WHEN billingtier = 0 THEN 1 ELSE billingtier END
```

The issue I have here is that this brings back both all columns that were previously 0 as 1 on one line, as well as another line where billing tier is actually 1, thus giving me two lines for '1', where it should be one line with both billing tier 1 and 0 added together

Data Expected

```
Year    UsageMonth  BillingTier2    SuppliesBilled  CreditKwH   DebitKwH    TotalKwh    CreditAmount    DebitAmount TotalAmount UnitRate    StandingCharge  CCL
2017    01/04/2017  1   3296    -4348786.008    7219573.706 2870787.699 -523979.1005    866478.4812 342499.3807 0.238118    22394.5114  10685.7546
2017    01/04/2017  4   27  -59415.7663 65843.4963  6427.73 -9269.5841  10359.9353  1090.3512   0.169632    118.5181    21.3836
2017    01/04/2017  5   515 -524035.4192    943647.2675 419611.8483 -105349.1449    189478.524  84129.3791  0.200493    6581.5  1567.7762
```

Data receiving

```
Year    UsageMonth  BillingTier2    SuppliesBilled  CreditKwH   DebitKwH    TotalKwh    CreditAmount    DebitAmount TotalAmount UnitRate    StandingCharge  CCL
2017    01/04/2017  1   3124    -4348786.008    7219573.706 2870787.699 -523979.1005    866478.4812 342499.3807 0.119305    22394.5114  10685.7546
2017    01/04/2017  4   27  -59415.7663 65843.4963  6427.73 -9269.5841  10359.9353  1090.3512   0.169632    118.5181    21.3836
2017    01/04/2017  5   515 -524035.4192    943647.2675 419611.8483 -105349.1449    189478.524  84129.3791  0.200493    6581.5  1567.7762
```

As you can see, all the sums and data match, bar the Supplies billed as 0 originally (172) missing from the Case statement when counted

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: What happens if you remove Billingtier from the GROUP BY?

Comment: It brings back one line, with all correct sums bar 'Supplies Billed', however when I try to sum this in the query I get 'Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator'

Comment: @Wil-Liam . . . I cannot follow what the question is really about.  Sample data and desired results would help.  It would also help if you simplified the results a bit.  Are all the columns really needed to describe the problem?

Comment: Sorry Gordon. Will update now

Comment: Updated @GordonLinoff, does this make the question and what's needed clearer?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using DISTINCT inside the COUNT function as below-

```
 SuppliesBilled = COUNT(DISTINCT c.CoreMPAN)
```

Its decreasing the number of COUNT if there are multiple c.CoreMPAN avilable with same value. Hoe you are aware of it. If this is not expected, you can try with removing the DISTINCT command from COUNT as below-

```
 SuppliesBilled = COUNT(c.CoreMPAN)
```